# When I send Objects of Javascript to my Spring boot application, it says "Invalid character found in the request target"

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot

I have searched for every possibility for this problem but couldn't figure out why is it happening.
It want to save an object in localstorage in javascript, then fetch this object and send data to my spring boot application. But when i call ajax, it gives me an error which is below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/product/cart/items?{%22cartItems%22:[{%22itemId%22:%22asfasfa%22,%22itemCount%22:2},{%22itemId%22:%22ijhar%22,%22itemCount%22:3}]}]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:491) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]
```

**JavaScript code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getAllItemsFromCart() {
    let product;
    product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    return product;
  }
  
  let itemsList = {};
  let cartItems = [];
  let items = {};
  items['itemId'] = 'asfasfa';
  items['itemCount'] = 2;
  cartItems.push(items);
  items = {};
  items['itemId'] = 'ijhar';
  items['itemCount'] = 3;
  cartItems.push(items);
  itemsList['cartItems'] = cartItems;

  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsList));
  let itemsList1 = getAllItemsFromCart();

  $.ajax({
    url: "[[@{/product/cart/items}]]",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemsList1),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
      console.log("This is success message")
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.debug(response.status + ":" + response.statusText);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      //talman.showAjaxLoader();
    },
    complete: function() {
      //talman.closeAjaxLoader();
    }

  });
});
```

**Java controller**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/cart/items",consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String addProductToCart(@RequestBody CartItemsBean itemList){  
   return "sucess";
}
```

**Bean**

```
class ItemsBean {
    private String itemId;
    private String itemCount;

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void setItemCount(String itemCount) {
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }
}

public class CartItemsBean {
    private List<ItemsBean> cartItems;

    public List<ItemsBean> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ItemsBean> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using get to send data in request body. Tried changing to Post

Comment: @Ijhar `localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsList));` While setting localStorage it's a Object which is correct. Then retrieving `product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));` is also correct, but product variable is declared as array and retrieving value from localStorage is object.

Comment: Hi @gkrthk, it does the work when i changed get request to post. thanks.

Comment: @Shiladitya, I have changed the question. Thanks for noting my mistake. But it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Spring Boot doesn't accept some special characters on QueryParams.

But I think in your case you need to use JSON.stringfy to wrap it.

By the way, It is a bit weird to have a GET receiving body or acting as a POST or PATCH.